# On Error not working with IE automation

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer, error-handling

My code is getting information from a website, but at some cases the HTML code with the information just isn't there, so I'm using `On Error` to handle it.

As you'll see in the code I'm runing through a list and getting information for each row (about 700 of them). At first the error was occuring at the 10th row, then I added `On Error GoTo 0`. After that it started to be thrown at row 13.

My configuration is already set to *Break on Unhandeled Errors*.

The run-time error number is:

> 91: Object variable or With block variable not set.

It is happening at the line between "** **"

```
Sub GetData_DK()

    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
    Dim URL As String
    Dim doc As HTMLDocument 'variable for document or data which need to be extracted out of webpage
    Dim onl As String
    Dim sto As String
    Dim pri As String
    FinalRow = tme.Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row

    Dim hyper As Workbook
    Set hyper = Workbooks.Open("path")
    FinalRowH = hyper.Sheets("tme").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    ThisWorkbook.Activate

    For a = 5 To FinalRow

        onl = ""
        sto = ""
        pri = ""

        For b = 5 To FinalRowH
            If (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("tme").Cells(a, 7).Value = hyper.Sheets("tme").Cells(b, 1).Value) Then
                URL = hyper.Sheets("tme").Cells(b, 3).Value
                Exit For
            End If
        Next b

        IE.navigate URL
        IE.Visible = True

        Do
            If IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE Then
                If IE.document.readyState = "complete" Then Exit Do
            End If
            Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
        Loop
        'Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:006")) ' For internal page refresh or loading


        Set doc = IE.document

        On Error Resume Next
        'gets HTLM class containing the value
        **onl = CStr(doc.getElementsByClassName("items-in-stock align-left")(0).innerText)**
        On Error GoTo 0
        If (onl = Chr(160) Or onl = " " Or onl = "   " Or onl = "" Or onl = vbNullString Or Left(onl, 9) = "Forventet") Then
            Cells(a, 8).Value = 0
        Else
            Cells(a, 8).Value = 1
        End If

        On Error GoTo price
        'repeats the process for stores
        sto = CStr(doc.getElementsByClassName("open-cas-tab")(0).innerText)
        sto = Left(sto, InStr(sto, " ") - 1)
        Cells(a, 9).Value = sto

price:
        On Error GoTo 0

        On Error Resume Next
        'repeats the process for price
        pri = CInt(CStr(doc.getElementsByClassName("product-price-container")(0).innerText))
        Cells(a, 10).Value = pri
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next a
End Sub
```

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If no elements are returned by using `getElementsByClassName` then you can test the `length` property and it will be 0. This is preferable to trying to skip the error generated if you try and access the 0th element because you assumed you would get a positive result.

So you can try this:

```
Set doc = IE.document

Dim objElements As Object
Set objElements = doc.getElementsByClassName("items-in-stock align-left")

If objElements.length > 0 Then
    ' some elements are returned - get the text from the first one
    onl = CStr(objElements(0).innerText)
Else
    ' nothing returned - lets handle it gracefully with no error
    MsgBox "No elements with that class!"
    '... prepare to exit 
End If

' do stuff with onl
```

Comment: This is brillaint! Thanks a lot for sharing your knowledge, Robin (: